# WCF Routing to an SSL-enabled service

Tags: wcf, ssl, routes

## Situation

I have modified the WCF Router sample to remove things that I'm not currently using, support clientVia rather than direct connections, and support HTTP and HTTPS.  When I use the router as an intermediary to an MLS-enabled service, everything works fine.  When I use the router as an intermediate to a TLS- and MLS-enabled service, I am failing on setting up the secure conversation.

I am connecting to the router using HTTP and trying to route to the SSL-enabled service using HTTPS.  If I try to use TLS to the router, then the router has to be on HTTPS.. and then I'd need the certificate to match, which is why I'm trying to setup the Client ==(HTTP)==> Router ==(HTTPS)==> Service relationship.

The message sent to establish TLS in the case of a direct connection (which works) is very different from the message sent to establish TLS when going through the router.  It looks like the client is dictating what's being sent, but shouldn't the client just be sending the MLS message and the router be establishing TLS and then sending the MLS message?

Code and config info follow, and the resultant traffic (direct and through router) as well.  Since no relevant changes have been made to the RouterBindingElement class, I've removed that from the code below (to save space).

Any suggestions as to how to get the SSL working would be greatly appreciated.

## **Code/Config**

### *RouterBinding class*

```
public enum RouterTransport
{
    Http = 0,
    Tcp = 1,
    NamedPipe = 2,
    Https = 3
}

public enum MessageEncoding
{
    Text,
    Binary,
    Mtom,
}

public class RouterBinding : Binding, IBindingRuntimePreferences
{
    MessageEncoding messageEncoding;
    RouterTransport transport;

    HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransport;
    HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsTransport;
    TcpTransportBindingElement tcpTransport;
    NamedPipeTransportBindingElement namedPipeTransport;

    TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textEncoding;
    MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement mtomEncoding;
    BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement binaryEncoding;

    public RouterBinding()
        : base()
    { 
        Initialize();
    }

    public RouterBinding(string configurationName)
        : this()
    { 
        ApplyConfiguration(configurationName);
    }

    public RouterBinding(RouterTransport transport)
        : this()
    {
        this.Transport = transport;

        if (transport == RouterTransport.NamedPipe || transport == RouterTransport.Tcp)
        {
            this.MessageEncoding = MessageEncoding.Binary;
        }
    }

    public RouterTransport Transport
    {
        get { return this.transport; }
        set
        {
            this.transport = value;
        }
    }

    public MessageEncoding MessageEncoding
    {
        get { return this.messageEncoding; }
        set
        {
            this.messageEncoding = value;
        }
    }

    public HostNameComparisonMode HostNameComparisonMode
    {
        get { return this.tcpTransport.HostNameComparisonMode; }
        set
        {
            this.tcpTransport.HostNameComparisonMode = value;
            this.namedPipeTransport.HostNameComparisonMode = value;
            this.httpTransport.HostNameComparisonMode = value;
            this.httpsTransport.HostNameComparisonMode = value;
        }
    }

    public int ListenBacklog
    {
        get { return this.tcpTransport.ListenBacklog; }
        set { this.tcpTransport.ListenBacklog = value; }
    }

    public long MaxBufferPoolSize
    {
        get { return this.tcpTransport.MaxBufferPoolSize; }
        set
        {
            this.tcpTransport.MaxBufferPoolSize = value;
            this.namedPipeTransport.MaxBufferPoolSize = value;
        }
    }

    public int MaxBufferSize
    {
        get { return this.tcpTransport.MaxBufferSize; }
        set
        {
            this.tcpTransport.MaxBufferSize = value;
            this.namedPipeTransport.MaxBufferSize = value;
        }
    }

    public int MaxConnections
    {
        get { return this.tcpTransport.ConnectionPoolSettings.MaxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint; }
        set
        {
            this.tcpTransport.MaxPendingConnections = value;
            this.namedPipeTransport.MaxPendingConnections = value;
            this.tcpTransport.ConnectionPoolSettings.MaxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint = value;
            this.namedPipeTransport.ConnectionPoolSettings.MaxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint = value;
        }
    }

    public long MaxReceivedMessageSize
    {
        get { return this.tcpTransport.MaxReceivedMessageSize; }
        set
        {
            this.tcpTransport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = value;
            this.namedPipeTransport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = value;
            this.httpTransport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = value;
            this.httpsTransport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = value;
        }
    }

    public bool PortSharingEnabled
    {
        get { return this.tcpTransport.PortSharingEnabled; }
        set { this.tcpTransport.PortSharingEnabled = value; }
    }

    public TransferMode TransferMode
    {
        get { return this.tcpTransport.TransferMode; }
        set
        {
            this.tcpTransport.TransferMode = value;
            this.namedPipeTransport.TransferMode = value;
            this.httpTransport.TransferMode = value;
            this.httpsTransport.TransferMode = value;
        }
    }

    bool IBindingRuntimePreferences.ReceiveSynchronously
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override string Scheme
    {
        get { return this.TransportElement.Scheme; }
    }

    void Initialize()
    {
        this.httpTransport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
        this.httpsTransport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
        this.tcpTransport = new TcpTransportBindingElement();
        this.namedPipeTransport = new NamedPipeTransportBindingElement();

        this.textEncoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
        this.mtomEncoding = new MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement();
        this.binaryEncoding = new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement();

        this.httpTransport.ManualAddressing = true;
        this.httpsTransport.ManualAddressing = true;
        this.tcpTransport.ManualAddressing = true;
        this.namedPipeTransport.ManualAddressing = true;

        this.transport = RouterTransport.Http;
        this.messageEncoding = MessageEncoding.Text;
    }

    void ApplyConfiguration(string configurationName)
    {
        RouterBindingCollectionElement bindingCollectionElement = RouterBindingCollectionElement.GetBindingCollectionElement();
        RouterBindingElement element = bindingCollectionElement.Bindings[configurationName];

        if (element == null)
        {
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(string.Format("ConfigInvalidBindingConfigurationName", configurationName, bindingCollectionElement.BindingName));
        }
        else
        {
            element.ApplyConfiguration(this);
        }
    }

    TransportBindingElement TransportElement
    {
        get
        {
            switch (this.transport)
            {
                case RouterTransport.Http:
                    return this.httpTransport;

                case RouterTransport.Https:
                    return this.httpsTransport;

                case RouterTransport.Tcp:
                    return this.tcpTransport;

                case RouterTransport.NamedPipe:
                    return this.namedPipeTransport;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    MessageEncodingBindingElement EncodingElement
    {
        get
        {
            switch (this.messageEncoding)
            {
                case MessageEncoding.Text:
                    return this.textEncoding;

                case MessageEncoding.Mtom:
                    return this.mtomEncoding;

                case MessageEncoding.Binary:
                    return this.binaryEncoding;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements()
    {
        BindingElementCollection elements = new BindingElementCollection();
        elements.Add(this.EncodingElement);
        elements.Add(this.TransportElement);

        return elements;
    }
}

public partial class RouterBindingCollectionElement : StandardBindingCollectionElement<RouterBinding, RouterBindingElement>
{
    // Removed for space
}
```

### *Router Class*

```
class SoapRouterExtension : IExtension<ServiceHostBase>
{
    IDictionary<string, Binding> bindings = new Dictionary<string, Binding>(2);

    public SoapRouterExtension()
    {
        this.bindings.Add("http", new RouterBinding("HttpTextSoap12RouterBinding"));
        this.bindings.Add("https", new RouterBinding("HttpsTextSoap12RouterBinding"));
    }

    public IDictionary<string, Binding> Bindings
    {
        get { return this.bindings; }
    }

    public void Attach(ServiceHostBase owner)
    { }

    public void Detach(ServiceHostBase owner)
    { }
}

sealed class SoapRouterServiceBehavior : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    void IServiceBehavior.Validate(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    { }

    void IServiceBehavior.AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection parameters)
    { }

    void IServiceBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        SoapRouterExtension extension = new SoapRouterExtension();
        serviceHostBase.Extensions.Add(extension);
    }
}

[SoapRouterServiceBehavior]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, ValidateMustUnderstand = false, AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public sealed class SoapRouter : IRequestReplyDatagramRouter, IDisposable
{
    SoapRouterExtension extension;

    public SoapRouter()
    {
        ServiceHostBase host = OperationContext.Current.Host;
        this.extension = host.Extensions.Find<SoapRouterExtension>();
    }

    #region SoapIntermediary Request-Reply Datagram
    Message IRequestReplyDatagramRouter.ProcessMessage(Message message)
    {
        EndpointAddress to = new EndpointAddress(message.Headers.To.AbsoluteUri);
        IRequestReplyDatagramRouter forwardingChannel = null;
        try
        {
            ChannelFactory<IRequestReplyDatagramRouter> factory = new ChannelFactory<IRequestReplyDatagramRouter>(this.extension.Bindings[to.Uri.Scheme], to);
            factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MustUnderstandBehavior(false));
            forwardingChannel = factory.CreateChannel();

            Console.WriteLine("Forwarding request " + message.Headers.Action + "...");
            Message response = forwardingChannel.ProcessMessage(message);

            Console.WriteLine("Forwarding response " + response.Headers.Action + "...");
            return response;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (forwardingChannel != null)
            {
                IClientChannel channel = forwardingChannel as IClientChannel;
                if (channel.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
                    channel.Abort();
                else
                    channel.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {

    }
}

public class ServiceDriver
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(SoapRouter));
        serviceHost.Open();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

### *Service Bindings*

The HTTPS binding's configuration is applied to the outgoing TLS connection.

```
  <routerBinding>
    <binding name="HttpTextSoap12RouterBinding"
             transport="Http"
             messageEncoding="Text"
             messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10"
             closeTimeout="01:00:00"
             openTimeout="01:00:00"
             receiveTimeout="01:00:00"
             sendTimeout="01:00:00">
    </binding>
    <binding name="HttpsTextSoap12RouterBinding"
             transport="Https"
             messageEncoding="Text"
             messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10"
             closeTimeout="01:00:00"
             openTimeout="01:00:00"
             receiveTimeout="01:00:00"
             sendTimeout="01:00:00">
    </binding>
  </routerBinding>
```

## Traffic

The places I have enclosed in {} have been modified, but no changes were made to the overall meaning.

### *Direct Connect*

```
CONNECT {provider.com:443} HTTP/1.1
Host: {provider.com}
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

### *Direct TLS Establishment*

```
POST {https://provider.com/service.svc} HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Host: {provider.com}
Content-Length: 4379
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/SCT</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:cfd9ec29-5e55-4154-8737-69f9b8b8bbb7</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_1">{https://provider.com/service.svc}</a:To>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2011-03-04T14:06:27.993Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2011-03-04T14:11:27.993Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
      <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-526477b6-8ed4-4873-bba5-7997589cd63c-1" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">    {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}</o:BinarySecurityToken>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <Reference URI="#_0">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>{aepZFE9EXqlXmuAf3RwcA6vXThQ=}</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#_1">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>{G9/ctKlSyWbRU78aQSLZmEbgdPw=}</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>{JAGbae324PdpRWOaIzihZygSAQVm3CJfOWbP6gsc0UJAGbae324PmYyqYMsgIMuCAlSHIj4yrEfbEL2XHt/nWlBfF0FgfhyqgcsEhc5vHR4kSmS7uKEoOZg8iMSDTGgk86YN5Z+UdB9ysIwe7KpxqrPmJAGbae324PdW8E2GWzY=}</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <o:SecurityTokenReference>
            <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-526477b6-8ed4-4873-bba5-7997589cd63c-1"/>
          </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
      <t:TokenType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct</t:TokenType>
      <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
      <t:Entropy>
        <t:BinarySecret u:Id="uuid-18de0e52-6a66-442a-8b18-41e4037b5139-1" Type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Nonce">{gjBI9ZhnJzJAGbae324P+APERNf9gqoJAGbae324PCA=}</t:BinarySecret>
      </t:Entropy>
      <t:KeySize>256</t:KeySize>
    </t:RequestSecurityToken>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

### *Client Post*

```
POST http://localhost.:8000/services/soap12/text HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost.:8000
Content-Length: 1146
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:1f5e02f6-ce41-4b66-a3a8-eb4014d5d1cb</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{https://provider.com/service.svc}</a:To>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <t:RequestSecurityToken Context="uuid-ffc85f7f-3ffa-4bc7-9174-5ab16948ec78-1" xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
      <t:TokenType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct</t:TokenType>
      <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
      <t:KeySize>256</t:KeySize>
      <t:BinaryExchange ValueType=" http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/tlsnego" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">{FgMBAEgBAABEAwFNcPIXogDSsEJYhXyu/adf4eFAe436TWvHqqv6ZN+FSQAAFgAEAAUACgAJAGbae324PYAEwASAGMBAAAF/wEAAQA=}</t:BinaryExchange>
    </t:RequestSecurityToken>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

### *Router Connect*

```
CONNECT {provider.com:443} HTTP/1.1
Host: {provider.com}
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

### *Router TLS Establishment*

```
POST {https://provider.com/service.svc} HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPoxyyRVZOBT9HmFHghQdaliEAAAAAAdkPtiI0y021hKG+IPwkNqyhfujS37tMnxoFJUL1/zoACQAA
Host: {provider.com}
Content-Length: 1146
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:1f5e02f6-ce41-4b66-a3a8-eb4014d5d1cb</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{https://provider.com/service.svc}</a:To>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <t:RequestSecurityToken Context="uuid-ffc85f7f-3ffa-4bc7-9174-5ab16948ec78-1" xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
      <t:TokenType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct</t:TokenType>
      <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
      <t:KeySize>256</t:KeySize>
      <t:BinaryExchange ValueType=" http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/tlsnego" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">{FgMBAEgBAABEAMIIEhzCCA/CgAwIBAgIQadf4eFAe436TWvHqqv6ZN+FSQAAFgAEAAUACgAJAGbae324PYAEwASAGMBAAAF/wEAAQA=}</t:BinaryExchange>
    </t:RequestSecurityToken>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

### *Error*

```
Secure channel cannot be opened because security negotiation with the remote endpoint has failed. This may be due to absent or incorrectly specified EndpointIdentity in the EndpointAddress used to create the channel. Please verify the EndpointIdentity specified or implied by the EndpointAddress correctly identifies the remote endpoint.
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a very similar scenario, except for the fact that we are using the default basicHttpBindings rather than our custom ones and configuration. Never-the-less, its still protocol bridging from HTTP to HTTPS.

One thing that isn't obvious, is where your client configuration is. The client service is specifiying a Security Mode of Tansport and so should the router. Here is what our, albeit simple, router configuration looks like.

```
    <services>
        <service name="System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService" behaviorConfiguration="RoutingServiceBehaviour">
            <endpoint
                address=""
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                name="reqReplyEndpoint"
                contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter"/>
        </service>
    </services>
```

Our client config:

```
    <client>
        <endpoint
            address="https://localhost/Service.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="SecureHttpBinding"
            contract="*"
            name="ServiceClientEndpoint"/>      
    </client>
```

The SecureHttpBinding is that specified by the client service

```
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="SecureHttpBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Our routing table determines what service to invoke depending on the criteria set in the filters.

Also, if your using self-signed certificates in your development environment, make sure they are registered properly. If your using two different machines you will have to export the service certificate to the router service machine. In that instance, your self signed certs will need to be registered using the machine name rather than localhost.

HTH.

Comment: So, I can't use a BasicHttpBinding from my client because I'm using what's made available via the WSHttpBinding (WS-Security, WS-Addressing, etc.).  Also, I'm not connecting directly from the client to the router - the router is a middle-man to external services, and I'm using ClientVia to go through it.  The SSL certificates are not under my control - the SSL-enabled services are external to our environment.

Comment: Sorry it's taken so long to get back - got swamped with other priorities.